# How do I change window size that is not Finder?

Tags: macos, window-manager

When I go to open in Photoshop or in FCPX or in other programs - window size is small.  Need the default to be larger. Any Ideas?

(I know how to resize Finder window)

Answer (score 1):

Drag the sides or corners of the window to your desired size. This is remembered across application launches.

Comment: Hmm When I open to add a picture on FB it is still the same small size.. same in Photoshop so.. still not working.